# Add attachment to a document which is in adding mode in SAP SDK

Tags: sdk, sapb1

I have developed an addon which adds scanned images to the invoice. If an invoice is added I have no problem, if it's in adding mode I can't allocate it because I don't have a DocEntry value which I need to pass.

Is it possible to add an attachment to a sales document in SDK which is in adding mode?

Comment: Assuming you're using DI-API: You can wrap adding the document and attaching the file in a single transaction, getting the DocEntry back from the first update by calling GetNewObjectKey on the company object within the transaction. 

If you're using Service Layer you can't do it in one transaction without writing some server-side Javascript to handle the new key.

Comment: Yes, I'm using DI-API. The idea of getting a DocEntry by GetNewObjectKey and putting it in the adding of a sales document transaction turned out to be working well. Thanks!

Comment: I've written it up properly as an answer, please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using DI-API:

Wrap the document creation and attaching the file to the document within a single transaction (see the SDK documentation on the `StartTransaction` method on the company object). After adding the document (still within the transaction) get the new DocEntry back from the first update by calling `GetNewObjectKey` on the company object. You can then use this key in the attachment update, finally committing the whole transaction (with `EndTransaction`).

If you're using Service Layer:

You can't do it in one transaction without writing some server-side Javascript to call. See **https://blogs.sap.com/2017/09/01/implementing-service-layers-script-engine/**

Comment: >Wrap the document creation and attaching the file to the document within a single transaction (see the SDK documentation on the StartTransaction method on the company object)

Are you saying to wrap the document creation using BeforeEvent = True and BeforeEvent = False? Does B1 allow to start a Transaction for system documents? Because B1 itself would have started the transaction. Can we control the transaction during the document Add standard functionality using SDK?

Comment: @AllSolutions no, my answer applies only to DI-API code, not something hooked into a UI-API event.